# Sending e-mail by System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient causes 'Mailbox unavailable, Spam Rejected'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

In a web application using asp.net 4.0, I use the class `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to send email.

This is my code:

```
Shared Function InviaMail(ByVal toAddress As String, ByVal TestoMsg As String, ByVal TestoSubject As String) As Boolean

    Dim from As New MailAddress("xxx@xxx.pro", "xxx.pro")
    Dim toDest As New MailAddress(toAddress, "")
    Dim mm As New MailMessage(from, toDest)


    Dim altView As AlternateView
    altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(TestoMsg, Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
    mm.AlternateViews.Add(altView)

    mm.Subject = TestoSubject
    mm.Body = TestoMsg
    mm.IsBodyHtml = True


    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

    Try
        smtp.Send(mm)
        mm.Dispose()
        mm = Nothing

        smtp.Dispose()
        smtp = Nothing

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

For some time now, whenever I try to send an email I get this error:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.2.0 Jhw61q00C2SXeFl01 Spam Rejected
```

I searched for hours for a solution, but did not find any information.

Please help me understand what is going on, and why I'm getting this error. If you need more information, I will provide it, but please try to help me.

Comment: I have no special knowledge about this, but isn't the mail server just refusing your message because it classifies it as junk ? Then, this has nothing to do with you code...

Comment: Is xxx@xxx.pro a valid email address?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the code you posted. Your Email message is being rejected by the recipient and (obviously) appears to be classified as spam for some reason. This could have to do with your content, subject line, or email-sending history from a specific IP address.

Comment: yes the code is correct, because even up to 15 days ago, everything worked regularly. It may be that Microsoft changed something with some updating?

Comment: I also tested the application locally and I experienced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

After more tests, I think the problem is due to the raising of the anti-spam policy of internet services providers. I will ask for this to my provider.

Comment: the provider has responded that the problem was due to the spam filter, as well as @Nick had suggested.